# How to get the number of the members to whom the message was sent to in discord.py v1.3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So here is my code -

````
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def sendall(ctx, *, message):
    for m in client.get_all_members():
        try:
            await m.send(message)
        except:
            pass
    await ctx.send(f"sent the message -\n```{message}``` to {ctx.guild.member_count} users.")
````

As of now, it just displays the member count of the server, I need it to display the number of members to whom the message was actually sent and to whom the message was not sent.
Example -
sent the message to [successfully sent] users. Could not send it to [error] users because they have dms closed.

Does anyone know how can I do so?

Comment: Create a list `myList = []`. Append `discord.Member.mention` String to list when it managed to send `myList.append(m.mention)`. Create a string from it `"Sent to following members: {}".format(", ".join(myList))`. Do the same for the people it didn't manage to send it to.

Comment: can you please explain with the code, I didnt really get it

Comment: [See image](https://i.imgur.com/oXWp9Dd.png). I create a dummy Member class. You can see how the code works. Not giving you the working code intentionally because you need to develop an understanding how it works so you can write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Basic approach:

Make an "counter" variable and just increment it on every successful sent message.

````py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def sendall(ctx, *, message):
    success, errors = 0, 0
    for m in client.get_all_members():
        try:
            await m.send(message)
            success += 1
        except:
            errors += 1
    await ctx.send(f"sent the message -\n```{message}``` to {success} users.\nUnable to send {errors} messages")
````

#### Counter approach:

You can also use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object from builtin [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) lib.
Thats would be useful if you want e.g. also know how many of each error occured.

````py
from collections import Counter

...

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def sendall(ctx, *, message):
    c = Counter()
    for m in client.get_all_members():
        try:
            await m.send(message)
            c["Success"] += 1
        except Exception as e:
            c[e] += 1
    await ctx.send(f"sent the message -\n```{message}``` to {c['Success']} users.\nUnable to send to {c[discord.Forbidden]} users: Missing Permissions")
````

*Also, please notice that you using `get_all_members` method. It will sent message to all **members** instances. Members are instances of users in guilds, so if, e.g., user is in two shared servers with a bot, he will get message twice. If you want to sent message to all **users** (which are unique users that bot can see), use [`users`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.users) attribute of `Client`*

Comment: on using client.users, I get an error -
`Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: You dont supposed to call it (`in client.users()`), this is list and it is not callable: `for m in client.users: ...`

Comment: it still shows the error - `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: I redacted answer, had missing string terminator, but its not related to your exception. Seems like you still try to call a list somewhere. Can you upload your current code to pastebin or smth like that?